# Trying to design the preview of a Square in a C# form

Tags: c#, winforms, shapes

[image: shows the problem]

I am trying to create a square by dragging the mouse while being clicked,I can create the sqaure alone but cant make it work with a preview.While it is being dragged previews shapes are not being erased for some reason and i dont really understand why this is happening.I will include pictures and videos of this happening because it is kinda hard to explain it on text.

How the Preview Works: There are 2 pens, the one is designed to erase the shape that is being created while the cursor travels through the form until it is let off and the square is designed

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Pen pen, eraser;
    Graphics graphics;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Point startPoint, endPoint;
    int choice;
    Boolean draw;
    int width;
    int height;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (draw && choice == 1)
        {
            width = e.Location.X - startPoint.X;
            height = e.Location.Y - startPoint.Y;
            width = height;
            Rectangle shape = new Rectangle(startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, width, height);
            graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, shape);
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            draw = false;
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (draw && choice == 1)
        {
            width = e.Location.X - startPoint.X;
            height = e.Location.Y - startPoint.Y;
            width = height;
            graphics.DrawRectangle(eraser, startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, width, height);
            graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, width, height);
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }
    }



    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        startPoint = e.Location;
        draw = true;
    }
```

Comment: Why you expect previous rectangle to be erased when your code draws the same rectangle twice? Looks like typo to me - you probably wanted to erase the previous rectangle instead of the same one as new to draw.

Comment: It doesnt draw the same thing twice it draws erases and draws again and that happens as long as the mouse moves

Comment: Use the Paint event to draw.

Comment: @AndrewSempros please take a look at the code in the post - it "erases" the same rectangle that would be "drawn" on the next line. I'm pretty sure you *see* different code that "erases" previous square and than changes w/h and draws new square with new size....

Comment: The thought of the code is correct, it has worked for other shapes i have made, its the way my professor wanted me to draw them,There is just a problem when i have to deal with shapes that have the height and width the same value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is taking a suboptimal approach. When you want to draw on a `PictureBox`, you can either call `pictureBox1.Refresh()` *or* you can `Invalidate` some or all of its `ClientRectangle`. The `PictureBox` responds by creating a `Graphics` context and firing the `Paint` event giving you the opportunity and the bounds in which you can draw.

It's important to know that the operating system is going to tell the `PictureBox` to redraw at various *other* times, not necessarily in response to any request by you, for example when the control or its parent resizes. If your drawing code is "somewhere else" and not contained in the `OnPaint` event handler, then anything you have drawn on the surface will be erased when that happens.

The image in your post is evidence of things gone horribly wrong in your approach. You're going to get a fresh canvas to draw on every time you call `Invalidate` as shown below. It's profoundly unnecessary to "erase" anything, so much so that if you want to keep previous squares that you've drawn you'll have to save them in some kind of document (see `RectanglesToRedraw` below).

[image: squares drawn from list]

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Capture starting point.
        pictureBox1.MouseDown += (sender, e) =>
            _mouseDownPoint = e.Location;

        // If Left button is down, tell the picture box to repaint itself.
        pictureBox1.MouseMove += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                _mouseCurrentPoint = e.Location;
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            }
        };

        // Use the Paint event to draw.
        pictureBox1.Paint += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                using (var pen = new Pen(Color.DarkRed, 2F))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"{_mouseDownPoint}{_mouseCurrentPoint}");
                    var width = _mouseCurrentPoint.X - _mouseDownPoint.X;
                    var height = _mouseCurrentPoint.Y - _mouseDownPoint.Y;
                    var side = Math.Max(width, height);

                    // Draw rectangle ON THE GRAPHICS PROVIDED.
                    _currentBounds = new Rectangle(_mouseDownPoint, new Size(side, side));
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, _currentBounds);

                    foreach (var savedRectangle in RectanglesToRedraw)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, savedRectangle);                           
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // If you don't want this square to erase the next
        // time you Invalidate, add it to your "Document".
        pictureBox1.MouseUp += (sender, e) => 
            RectanglesToRedraw.Add(_currentBounds);
    }
    Point _mouseDownPoint = default;
    Point _mouseCurrentPoint = default;
    Rectangle _currentBounds = default;
    List<Rectangle> RectanglesToRedraw { get; } = new List<Rectangle>();
}
```

Comment: I dont think you quite understood the problem tho,How does this help in the preview of the shape?

Comment: I am not drawing using OnPaint i am drawing on a picturebox using the DrawRectangle

Comment: Trying to run the form but nothing shows up, the file is loading fine but there are no referenaces in the different functions

Comment: Right i fixed it and now i can run the code, what you have made is exactly how i want it to work.But i would like it to work using the DrawRectangle method since thats the way my professor showed me. If you could alter my code and make it work like yours using the Pen, the eraser and the DrawRectangle that would be awesome

Comment: There is nothing shady about this,There is just a problem with the cordinates on the drawRectangle of the square that makes it look like that when is being drawn.I really need help

Comment: <<that resizing or maximizing the window is going to make all the shapes disappear altogether>>This doesnt matter at all it can be doing that but we wont be resizing in the project or anything, just want the shape to work

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/draw-squares-in-picture-box.git) the code I used to test this answer.